# How would you store menu of a restaurant in a database?

Tags: database

If I have 5 restaurant and 5 menu. What is the best way to represent this data in a normalized database.

Comment: Could you supply any more information? This is pretty vague!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, since you're working with different restaurants, you need a `restaurant` table. That's what it must contain:

```
restaurant

id | name | adress | phone_number | etc
```

Then for the 5 different menus, you would need this `menu` table:

```
menu

id | restaurant_id
```

You would also need a table for the items:

```
item

id | item_name | item_price
```

Now you need a table to make a relation between all of them:

```
menu_items

menu_id | item_id
```

This is normalized, as the table that correlates them is the `menu_items`. How you'll be treating them is only programming logic.

For the constraints, you need to make a foreign key relationship between those:

```
restaurant.id and menu.restaurant_id

menu_items.restaurant_id and restaurants.id

menu_items.menu_id and menu.id

menu_items.item_id and item.id
```